# Any suggestions on how to remove multiple features from geojson file quickly?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I have a geojson file I would like to simplify. It currently contains about 33,000 records. The file is of all the roads in the state of Nevada and I would like to be able to remove the roads in cities(i.e. Las Vegas) because it is taking up a chunk of data, when those roads are easy to see from a leaflet map so they don't need to be drawn.

I have tried to use geojson.io and other geojson generators to try and remove the roads but it will take way too much time to manually delete all these roads individually. I was hoping there would be a something similar that I could draw a rectangle over the area I want to delete and it would remove all of those features.

**EDIT**
I have tried to simplify the layer with http://mapshaper.org/ but the file is still to large. If I try to simplify it more, the resulting roads would not be very accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways that you can do this, but since you have already used mapshaper to simplify, we can use mapshaper to clip or erase features.

Using geojson.io I created a quick bounding box geojson called clip.json - with this I can remove features outside or inside of this feature from the roads geojson file. While I created a geojson to use to clip/erase features, you could use a pre-existing file the same way.

Drag both geojson files into mapshaper.org. Toggle the view of the road geojson (as only one layer is shown at at time, the current layer is displayed on the top ribbon and can be changed by clicking on the name.)

Once viewing the roads geojson, open the page's console window (top right of the page) and type:

```
erase clip.json
```

This will give you something like (using Nevada and a basic bbox for Las Vegas):

[image]

Now you can easily export the file and use it as needed.

To achieve the opposite effect, you would use `clip`: `clip clip.json`